# iCloud never gets empty after synchronisation

Tags: ios, icloud

I'm working with iCloud and core data in iOS 7.

I thought that data was only transiting through iCloud to different devices.
But when I finish synchronising my devices, iCloud still shows me that it has the full size data of my app.

For exemple, if my data is 100 MB, iCloud for my app shows me 100 MB and my whole storage size is :

5 GB - 100 MB.

I don't want to use iCloud as a backup system, but it seems to me that iCloud is acting to be the True copy of all my data.

Is this normal ? or I'm missing something !

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how iCloud works. It's not a transfer mechanism, it's a synchronization system. It keeps iCloud data on the server as well as on the devices.

Among other things, this is because

- It means that it's possible to sync data from one device to another even if they're not connected at the same time.
- It means it's possible to install the app on a new device and immediately get all the user's data from the cloud server.

What you describe is "working normally" for iCloud.